# How to rid of some of the cells in the Dataframe with strings and 'inf' values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-extraction

I'm new to pandas and data science in general. I have the data which I have to get the mean of, but the data is very big(around 15000 rows), and some of the cells of the data frame has strings( like #NEXT? which gives the value -inf when calculating the mean) and some when values when dividing( some values are zeros) give NaN but some of them gives values 'inf' so the total mean comes as 'inf'. I want to get rid of these types of values. Can someone please tell me how to overlook these values when operating on a column?

I tried many things, like looping over the entire column of a data frame and getting rid of the values.

```
x_wto_inf = []
for i in reports.iterrows():
    x = reports['y_cost'][i] / reports['z_calls'][i]
    if x == 'inf':
        break
    else:
        x_wto_inf.append(x)
x_wto_inf_df = pd.DataFrame(x_wto_inf, columns = ['x_wto_inf'])
```

This gives me an error.

```
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

I also tried to just read all the values of the column in the data frame and then putting that into the loop which is given below.

```
y_cost_var = reports['y_cost']
y_cost_var_val = y_cost_var.values
y_cost_var_val


z_calls_var = reports['z_calls']
z_calls_var_val = z_calls_var.values
z_cost_var_val
```

and then dividing the values as arrays but it's also giving me an error.

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), NumPy.newaxis (`None`), and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

can someone please help me with this? I will forever be grateful for it. Thank you.

> UPDATE

I Tried this piece of code,

```
reports_Copy1 = reports_Copy.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)
reports_Copy1 = reports_Copy.replace('#NEXT?', 0)
reports_Copy1.iloc[3177]
reports_Copy1.iloc[3184]
```

when printing these results, it shows all these values as zero, as you can see below,

```
responsiveness                                         0
```

but taking the mean of it still gives me `'-inf'`

I don't know how to solve this, can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to first replace infs to NaN:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

and then use the dropna:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all")
```

Comment: If you do not want to drop the rows, you can filter for nan and set 0 as value in this case.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. But There's one more problem, how do I get rid of the '#NEXT?' or any string in a certain cell of the data frame as to when I do operations, the string gives me an error. It will really help me. Thanks again.

Comment: You can just check the type by using lambda function and replace strings with np.nan
    df.col = df.col.apply(lambda x: np.nan isinstanceof(x, str) else x)